# mutt automatically add CR to newline when attaching a file?

Tags: email, newline, mutt

I have just started using Mutt and I have a minimal configuration just to be able to send mail. I can send mail OK, the problem is when I try to attach a source file, the file's new line characters are automatically translated from LF to CRLF. I can confirm this by using hexdump. I also suppose that this problem originates from Mutt, because the problem doesn't appear when using other mail clients (like Gmail).

My .muttrc looks like this:

```
set from="Anh Le <anhlq2110@gmail.com>"
set imap_user=anhlq2110@gmail.com

set smtp_url="smtps://anhlq2110\@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com/"

set editor="vim"
set markers=no
set include=yes
set forward_format="Fwd: %s"
```

I've searched around for this problem but can't find any useful information. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, when you send mail is in HTML format, in this case, you have to add

```
<br>
```

at the end of line.